# Lost Messages While Transferring Exchange to Gmail Using Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap

Recently I began transferring old messages from a work (Exchange) account to Gmail using the IMAP connector in Outlook.  It had been going fine for a few days as I organized and then moved folders.

Then, when I tried to drag over a large number of messages from the Inbox, I ran into [this known Outlook bug](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Outlook-for-Windows-crashes-on-outlmime-dll-moving-email-to-an-IMAP-account-ee8e5788-7807-49a8-a139-0685f5bfa418?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1), even though it had been working fine, previously.  The updates to Outlook that are said to fix this problem have not worked for me.  The crash message is as follows:

> Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEDF0BE79C (OUTLMIME.DLL) in
>   OUTLOOK.EXE: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0x0000000000000002.

My problem, other than the continued crashing, is that I dragged the messages from the Exchange account, and so they no longer appear there, but only a small fraction of them made it into the Gmail account before the crashes started happening.  Now it seems maybe they're in some sort of limbo where Outlook wants to sync them over to Gmail, but since it crashes so quickly after launch (while syncing), it is unable to do so.

I'm wondering if there's any approach I can take that will call these messages back from limbo instead of just considering them lost.  In `AppData/Local/Microsoft/Outlook`, I can still see the `NST` and `OST` for the Exchange account, as well as the `OST` for the Gmail account.  There are `DAT` files in the RoamCache that begin with `Stream_`.  Should I try backing up some assortment of all these files, and removing/reconnecting my IMAP Gmail connector?

**UPDATE**

I have gotten Outlook to stop crashing by setting up a new profile.  However, the messages that were in the middle of transferring do not appear in either account, neither on the server (i.e. Outlook 365 web client/Gmail web client), nor in the Outlook desktop client.  I'm assuming they're trapped somewhere in a data file on my machine and I'm wondering if there's any way to get the new profile to see that there are still a few hundred messages that should be uploaded to the IMAP/Gmail account.

Comment: Backup your profile, create a new profile, see if that solves the problem.  Be sure you have the July update installed though.  OST files are useless in a case like this

Comment: @Ramhound - I'm curious if you could elaborate on what you mean about the OST files being useless.  Also, do you have any insight about where the in-limbo messages are being stored while they are invisible in the origin and destination accounts?  I do have the July updates, by the way.

Comment: .OST is worthless in a case like this because it cannot be used to recover your emails.

Comment: @Ramhound - If I can't connect the old data files, I'm not sure I understand how a new profile will help recover those in-limbo messages.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion?  You have nothing to lose.  You are going to be able to restore the profile if you performed the first part of the suggestion.]

Comment: @Ramhound - (1 of 2) Partially. I backed up the old and created a new profile and added the Exchange account (the source). I hesitated to add the Gmail/IMAP account (the destination) because I struggled to connect the old data file for the Exchange account (where I guess the in-limbo messages are) to the new profile

Comment: @Ramhouse - (2 of 2) I'm assuming somewhere on the machine there is a file of some sort that knows the Exchange messages have not been sent to the IMAP account. I'm just worried about losing those, since the messages are not present on the Exchange server or the Gmail server. 
 I'll finish your suggestion and see what I can figure out.

Comment: @Ramhound - Okay, I've completed your suggestion.  I see both accounts in my new profile, and the crashing has stopped.  As expected, the missing messages are not in either account.  Is the idea now that I swap the data file the Exchange account is using to the old one where (presumably?) the in-limbo messages are so that the transfer can resume?

Comment: As a Exchange user you cannot modify the data files used by the server

Comment: @Ramhound - So, is the bottom line here that there's no way to recover the in-limbo messages?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue with a utility called Kernel OST Viewer.  It was able to open my corrupted OST and browse the messages that got lost in the transfer.  For my needs, this was good enough, but if I had absolutely needed those messages to be transferred from the damaged profile to my Gmail account, they have a paid version of the utility that can do that, and a number of other export methods.